# Vectorised addition for 2 short int vectors using AVX2

Tags: c, x86, simd, avx2

I am facing problem in performing addition operation on 2 short (16bit integer) vector types using the AVX2 instruction set. 
I have built the code but am getting an error in the addition command, probably because of the wrong syntax.
I am creating 2 vectors with the following code:

```
short int si1[16] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
short int si2[16] ={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

__m256i i1 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)si1);
__m256i i2 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)si2);
```

and I am trying to perform addition using the following code:

```
__m256i result = _mm256_add_si256(i1,i2);
```

I understand for 16 bit integers we use scalar suffix, but the compiler gives the error of implicit declaration of function to add command.

Comment: So just to be clear, the compiler says that `_mm256_add_epi16` does not exist?

Comment: Well, there's no such thing as `_mm256_add_si256()`.

Comment: I think that the error "implicit declaration of function" does mean that the function/method doesn't exist.

Comment: @Romal probably, but which function? You've shown `_mm256_add_si256` (which indeed does not exist and cannot exist - and even if it did exist it wouldn't add shorts), but then in the next paragraph you seem to be going towards `_mm256_add_epi16` (if that's what "scalar suffix" means)

Comment: @harold, I tried `_mm256_add_epi16`. The program compiles. But it is giving segmentation fault. Got to look into if there is some error in the code(which i think there isn't as the code runs for 32 bit integer configuration).

Comment: @Romal that's often caused by alignment issues, which you're likely to have here (short arrays don't have to be 32-aligned, but you do assume that)

Comment: There's some issue with the vectorized commands for short data type and its addition.

Comment: @harold, what do you mean by 32-aligned? or what is alignment in this?

Comment: Change `_mm256_load_si256` to `_mm256_loadu_si256`.

Comment: Use `alignas(32) short int si1[16] = { ... };`

Comment: @PaulR  Hi, Okay it works with the change you said.

Comment: But i am experiencing another issue here. Can you have a look at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/89362/performing-avx-instructions-in-c-along-with-thread-parallelism

Comment: Yes, you either need to align your data or use unaligned loads/stores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With comments from people and some of my experimentation I solved the problem by using unaligned operation. So my code finally looks like this-

```
short int si1[16] =
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
short int si2[16] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

__m256i i1 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i *) si1);
__m256i i2 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i *) si2);

    __m256i result = _mm256_adds_epi16(i2, i1);
```

This works and use -O2 optimization flag(on gcc) while trying to compile the program in case you are using multi threading because the optimization was the reason I was getting some other errors (execution time for big workload was higher for more threads as compared to single thread).